# State React, why it doesn't change fast

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx

The question is, why when we type "1" in textarea console.log shows empty string, but actually textInput = "1"?

```
const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('')

const inputAction= (e) => {
   setTextInput(e.target.value);
   console.log(textInput);
};

<textarea
value={textInput}
onChange={inputAction}
></textarea>
```

Comment: The answer is "closures". Your state variable is block scoped to the current render, therefore it doesn't reflect the new value until it is redeclared on the next render.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`setTextInput` does not immediately update the value of `textInput` - instead, it queues a re-render, and during that render the value will be updated. This is a pretty common React question, I'd encourage you to read up on [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to get a better sense for what's going on here.